# Simple Mathematical Equation for the Geotherm

Tags: geophysics, geothermal-heat, mantle

Hi I need a simple equation (polynomial third straight) for a PerpleX simulation to represent the mantle geotherm. The geotherms  I have found on the internet so far (unfortunately I don't have the websites anymore) were all too complex for me to use for my simulation. Do any of you know suitable literature or have you written a geotherm gradient for PerpleX?

Comment: The reason why the geotherms you found are complex is because the truth is complex. If you want a "simple equation", then that is only possible if you make approximations. The question for you then is "what kinds of approximations would you be willing to make"?